# How to get values from another table and insert the result into another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to to build a basic sql query where I have a table of petrol stations and another table of POI in my sql database and I would like to get all petrol stations within a radius of a POI

I have the following query:

```
        SELECT *, ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(15.4383252) )
 * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lat ) ) * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lng ) - radians(47.0450591) ) 
+ sin( radians(15.4383252) ) * sin(radians(petrol_stations.lat)) ) ) 
AS distance FROM petrol_stations HAVING distance < 500
```

and it seems to work fine, however I have to hard-code the coordinates of the POI into the query. Is it possible to adapt the query such that the POI coordinates are pulled from the other table if provided with the name such as `main square`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a georef poi table as

```
  table_poi 

  id    name    lat           lng 
  1     my_poi  47.0450591 15.4383252
```

you could try a cross  join for related all your petrol_stations with all your POI

```
  SELECT *
    , ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(table_poi.lng) )
      * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lat ) ) * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lng ) 
           - radians(table_poi.lat) ) 
      + sin( radians(table_poi.lng) ) * sin(radians(petrol_stations.lat)) ) ) 
  AS distance 
  FROM petrol_stations  
  CROSS JOIN table_poi 
  HAVING distance < 500
```

or using where (as requested  by MarlinPierce)

```
  SELECT *
    , ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(table_poi.lng) )
      * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lat ) ) * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lng ) 
           - radians(table_poi.lat) ) 
      + sin( radians(table_poi.lng) ) * sin(radians(petrol_stations.lat)) ) ) 
  AS distance 
  FROM petrol_stations  
  CROSS JOIN table_poi 
  WHERE ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(table_poi.lng) )
      * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lat ) ) * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lng ) 
           - radians(table_poi.lat) ) 
      + sin( radians(table_poi.lng) ) * sin(radians(petrol_stations.lat)) ) ) < 500
```

and if you want filter for a POI name

```
  SELECT *
    , ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(table_poi.lng) )
      * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lat ) ) * cos( radians( petrol_stations.lng ) 
           - radians(table_poi.lat) ) 
      + sin( radians(table_poi.lng) ) * sin(radians(petrol_stations.lat)) ) ) 
  AS distance 
  FROM petrol_stations  
  WHERE table_poi.name like '%your_poi_name%'
  CROSS JOIN table_poi 
  HAVING distance < 500
```

Comment: Should be `WHERE distance < 500`

Comment: @MarlinPierce  if the OP want use the alias he need  the having clause  .. otherwise the where can't use the distance column name alias

Comment: That would be true if you were using a `GROUP BY` and aggregated functions.  The aliased aggregated expression would have to be in a `HAVING`.  But if you are not using `GROUP BY` the `HAVING` is invalid.

Comment: @MarlinPierce  i have test (right now) with mysql 5.7 and having wthiout group by  .. work fine ..and lloking to mysql select sintax the haing clause is not sub related to the group by  but is independent https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html ...anyway your comment is conceptually valid  .. but to the fact that having work on the result set  ..is possible filter the resulting values with having

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where would I insert the name of the poi in the query from scaisEdge, would I then just add `WHERE table_poi.name like 'my_poi'`?